# Error in Thread()

Tags: java, android

This is my *getAllFriends* method with *Thread*

```
   ArrayList<User> users;
  private void getAllFriends()
{
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                api=new Api(Account.access_token, Constants.API_ID);
                users = api.getFriends(Account.user_id,"name",null,null,null);
                user_name = users.get(0).first_name;
                api = null;

                runOnUiThread(successRunnableFriends);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
Runnable successRunnableFriends = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        user_name = users.get(0).first_name;
        Toast.makeText(c, String.valueOf(users.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Shows 166
    }
};
```

It gives me certain *user_name* and *user.size*, which means that *users* in not empty, **BUT** whenever I try call *getAllFriends*, it Toastes *null*

```
    public void getFriends(Context _c) {
    c = _c;
    getAllFriends();
    if(users.size() == 0)
        Toast.makeText(c,String.valueOf(user_name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//null
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `getAllFriends` doesn't return anything (its return type is void).

Comment: @immibis it Toastes null

Comment: Your code is not understandable. The Api.getFriends accept 5 paramters while the getFriends accept one parameter. Post a more complete code so we can analyse

Comment: @Snake Runnable *successRunnableFriends* shows that it works

Comment: I know it works, but I am not sure which line is calling what line. Are these from different classes? Where the getFriends(Context) being called from?

Comment: @Snake from another class

Comment: Sorry, can't help. Your answers are too short and you are not helping us investigate. Once you elaborate more on the problem or post more code that shows where getFreinds are being called from, we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your thread in `getAllFriends()` is definitely running before the thread `successRunnableFriends`, then you might have an issue with the declaration of

```
ArrayList<User> users;
```

This should rather be

```
volatile ArrayList<User> users;
```

because otherwise the JVM is allowed to cash the value for a newly started thread.

Check for instance this nice [article](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.de/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html).

***p.s.***: if volatile doesn't work, consider the following. At the point of time when

```
if(users.size() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(c,String.valueOf(user_name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

is executed the `api.getFriends(Account.user_id,"name",null,null,null);` has most likely not been completed. So the Toast shows `null`. What you have to ensure is that the assignment to `users` in `getAllFriends()` is done before you access it in another thread. Use `wait` and `notify` to achieve this. Check for instance [this article](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) for the basics.

Comment: it still gives a null

Comment: And you are really sure that `users`  gets filled with at least one item and before `successRunnableFriends` is running?

Comment: Ok, in your the line `if(users.size() == 0) Toast.makeText...` you use the member `user_name` which is probably assigned in another thread as well. If I'm right you have to declare `user_name` with volatile as well. But, by the way, why are you checking for `users.size() == 0`? In this case `user_name` gets never assigned in `user_name = users.get(0).first_name` because you try to reference an item with `get()`which is not existing. It will end up in the `catch` block ....

Comment: before *successRunnableFriends* I can't Toast it and cheak it, during *successRunnableFriends* it has 166 elements and in *getFriends* it has 0 elements

Comment: Did you try the `volatile String user_name`?